# Changing the IP address of Azure Virtual Network cloud service

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-cloud-services, static-ip-address, azure-virtual-network

I have 2 different virtual networks set up in azure. The first of these virtual networks contains virtual machines in which I am able to set the internal virtual network IP as 10.101.1.4, 10.101.1.5, 10.101.1.6 on the virtual machines by using the preview portal to set the IP address

In my other virtual network I have a VPN connection and from the virtual network I add a Cloud service which we have informed the other side of the VPN will be available on 10.103.1.4 but for some reason this has now changed to 10.103.1.5

Is there any means of ensuring that the cloud service will always be deployed to the 10.103.1.4 IP address within the virtual network?

Answer (score 1):

an compute instance or an azureVM get an IP-Adresse via DHCP and the lease time is 100+ years. to set a specific IP-Adresse to an azureVM/compute instance you can define a "static ip reservation" in your own VNET to this instance. e.g. via powershell, the new portal or via your cloud service configuration schema. 
check out this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/reserved-ip-addresses/

regards

patrick